# How to convert Contents of Rich Text Area?

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript, custom-field, richtextarea

I am Querying Rich text area field using sforce connection in vf. I am getting the result in html format. I need only the text with the applied css format.

how to achieve this.

SOQL Result:

```
<i><b>france</b></i>
```

Required Result in Java Script:
***france***

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one where you can get inner value of the text:

```
var content = "<p>Dear sms,</p><p>This is a test notification for push message from center II.</p>";

var text = $(content).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the html for rich Text field using [stripHtmlTags(htmlInput)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_stripHtmlTags) Or you can apply regular expression to remove html tags.

for e.g 
String target = someString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

javascript :- var target = str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');

Comment: Yes, I can strip the characters and convert to plain text. But i need the styles should be applied to the text for eg; (bold,italic) to text france.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?

Comment: when i query rich text area field its returning content wrapped with html tags. I need the content only with applied html formatting.